# Could someone explain why my print statement isn't printing both variables on one line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, output

as the question states, I don't understand why the output is in two separate lines rather than one. Here's my code:

```
import os

items=os.listdir("C:/output")

for names in items:
    if names.endswith(".txt"):
        with open('C:/output/' + names, encoding="utf8") as currentFile:
            for i, line in enumerate(currentFile):
                if ('Date Released' in line):
                    print(line + names)
                else:
                    i = i + 1
                if i > 11:
                    break
```

I've tried using a comma for the print statement like so: print(line, names), that did not work. I've also tried using .format(line, names) at the end of the print statement, no luck with that either.

The output looks like this:

```
Date Released:  12/14/2016
 1393-004IP_ B_ C2  filename.txt
Date Released:  4/11/2017
 1476-002 IP, filename.txt
Date Released:  9/25/2015
 1987-XXX IP_B_filename.txt
Date Released: 4/9/2015
 2044-002IP_A_C1  filename.txt
```

etc.

It would be very helpful to get the date and filename in the same line so I can put it into excel very easily. Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because every line ends with a new line character `'\n'`. You need to strip them, using say `str.rstrip`:

```
for i, line in enumerate(currentFile):
   line = line.rstrip()
   if 'Date Released' in line:
       print(line + ' ' + names)
```

Comment: Oh my goodness... Thank you! I'm new to python, wasn't aware of the built in '\n' , started using it a day or two ago.